# The database generated a key that is already in use, caused by Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a legacy production software that uses LINQ to SQL, and it's own database. I wanted to create a trigger on one of the tables in that database and have it do a few joins and keep a field in another database current with its values. What has happened now is with the trigger I get this error in my legacy application:
"The database generated a key that is already in use."

If I remove the trigger, everthing works as per usual.

Here is the trigger:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @action as char(1);

if exists(SELECT * from inserted) and exists (SELECT * from deleted)
    begin
        SET @action = 'UPDATE';
        INSERT INTO ste.dbo.Logs([LogEvent],[RaisedBy],[LogTime])
        SELECT
            itemID,
            'ListLineItem (' + ListLineItemID + '): ' + @action,
            GETDATE()
        FROM INSERTED
    end
If exists (Select * from inserted) and not exists(Select * from deleted)
    begin
        SET @action = 'INSERT';
        update soli
            set soli.itemRefNumber = wo.RefNum,
                soli.itemIssueDate = wo.IssueDate
        from ste.dbo.ListLineItems soli
        join INSERTED woli on soli.ListLineTxnID = woli.ListLineItemID
        join cse.dbo.item wo on woli.itemID = wo.IDKey

        SELECT
            itemID,
            'ListLineItem (' + ListLineItemID + '): ' + @action,
            GETDATE()
        FROM INSERTED
    end
If exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(Select * from inserted)
    begin 
        SET @action = 'DELETE';
        update soli
            set soli.itemRefNumber = null,
                soli.itemIssueDate = '19000101'
        from ste.dbo.ListLineItems soli
        join deleted woli on soli.ListLineTxnID = woli.ListLineItemID
        join cse.dbo.item wo on woli.itemID = wo.IDKey
        SELECT
            itemID,
            'ListLineItem (' + ListLineItemID + '): ' + @action,
            GETDATE()
        FROM deleted
    end
 END
```

Thoughts?

Comment: The code is failing at an Insert. The key that is "already in use" is the Inserted IDKEY...

Answer (score 0):

In place of auto generated primary key code should use guuid. As I think your application is running in multi threaded mode with a race condition between multiple thread leading to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to post useful information. Why do you cut off the actual declaration of the trigger name, table, and type? You also cut off the last part of the trigger code. Next, post the complete text of all errors - not your interpretation. Finally, read all you can about triggers and problems the inexperienced find trying to write them.

Your problems? In your insert and delete blocks, you attempt to return a resultset - **DON'T**. Did you copy/paste incorrectly? And what did you intend when you defined @action as a single character string? You don't really use it as a variable so why add the complexity of assigning a multi-character string to it when a literal can be used?

Lastly, the error message you posted sounds like it was generated by your application. The most likely explanation is that the app "sees" the resultset of your trigger and misinterprets the information.

And one last comment - what happens when a merge statement statement causes the trigger to execute? Will it work correctly and record the appropriate information? Be careful what you assume and how you test.